# Admin Panel In Mobile Apps || How to Add and hide from local user || React native || Android

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-application

I am web Developer now started Mobile App,  when we develop web application we have some restricted routes that use for Administration, we used credentials and goes to admin panel that is completely hide from user. so question is that how we can add admin panel in mobile app that should be hide from local user. but now there is no search bar or browser in mobile so how we can do.
just looking for hint or idea and thanks in Advance

Comment: After login success of admin panel just use AsyncStorage to save admin details or id or any value . It acts like a session in mobile application which you can delete after logout

Comment: Don't know about React, but I use Quasar/Vue and it has builtin v-touch-hold event. I have a secret debug page in one of my apps that can be accessed by touch and hold a certain non visible area for a number of seconds, then it opens a special page. surely React must have these touch/hold/swipe  events.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think it would be better for you to develop a different app for administration. why do you need to deliver to regular users all your admin capabilities (even if hidden)? I don't see any point in doing that